# Windows batch SQL Server script - Breaking to subroutines

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file

I've written a batch script with several intentions in mind:

- Generate a collated DDL script that is environment specific
- Support the execution of the collated script through SQL Server's sqlcmd executable

The script is as follows:

```
::
:: mydb-load-v1.bat
:: 
:: Script for dropping and re-creating version 1 of the MyDB database DDL
::
ECHO off
CLS
ECHO( 
ECHO #####################################################################
ECHO # MyDB Version 1 Load Script      
ECHO #
ECHO # Started at %DATE% %TIME%              
ECHO #
ECHO # Script format is: 
ECHO # mydb-load-v1.bat 
ECHO #
ECHO #####################################################################
ECHO(

:: Initialize script variables
SET "DDL_DIR=%CD%\ddl"
SET "DDL_TEMP_FILE=mydb-v1-ddl.final.sql.tmp"
SET "DDL_FILE=mydb-v1-ddl.final.sql"
SET "SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT="
SET "SCRIPT_SERVER="
SET "SCRIPT_DATABASE="
SET "SCRIPT_RESULT_LOG=load-ddl-results.log"
SET "DB_USERNAME="
SET "DB_PASSWORD="
SET "SCRIPT_EXECUTE="

:: Which environment are we using? 
SET /P "SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT=Please enter the environment (0=Local, 1=Dev, 2=QA, 3=UAT, 4=Prod):"

IF %SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT%==0 (
    SET SCRIPT_SERVER=myserver\SQLEXPRESS
    SET SCRIPT_DATABASE=MyDBDev
)
IF %SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT%==1 (
    SET SCRIPT_SERVER=devserver
    SET SCRIPT_DATABASE=MyDBDev
)
IF %SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT%==2 (
    SET SCRIPT_SERVER=qaserver
    SET SCRIPT_DATABASE=MyDBQA
)
IF %SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT%==3 (
    SET SCRIPT_SERVER=uatserver
    SET SCRIPT_DATABASE=MyDBUAT
)
IF %SCRIPT_ENVIRONMENT%==4 (
    SET SCRIPT_SERVER=prodserver
    SET SCRIPT_DATABASE=MyDBPROD
)

:: Checks if the ddl file exists, deletes it if so and then creates a new blank one
ECHO(
ECHO Generating the %DDL_FILE% file
ECHO(
IF exist %DDL_TEMP_FILE% (
    del %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
)
IF exist %DDL_FILE% (
    del %DDL_FILE%
)
copy NUL %DDL_TEMP_FILE%

IF exist %SCRIPT_RESULT_LOG% (
    del %SCRIPT_RESULT_LOG%
)

:: Write out the DDL initialization
ECHO USE [%SCRIPT_DATABASE%] >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%

:: Append the individual drop scripts to the new script file
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\drop-dbo-tEmailLastScan.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\drop-dbo-userExternalSysLogin.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\drop-dbo-userPasswordHistory.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\drop-dbo-userProfile.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\drop-dbo-userLogin.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%

:: Append the individual create scripts to the new script file
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\create-dbo-userLogin.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\create-dbo-tEmailLastScan.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\create-dbo-userExternalSysLogin.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\create-dbo-userPasswordHistory.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
TYPE %DDL_DIR%\create-dbo-userProfile.sql >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO GO >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%
ECHO( >> %DDL_TEMP_FILE%

REN %DDL_TEMP_FILE% %DDL_FILE%

SET /P "SCRIPT_EXECUTE=Would you like to run the script now (0=No, 1=Yes):"

IF [%SCRIPT_EXECUTE%]=="1" (
    ECHO(
    ECHO Running sqlcmd.exe
    ECHO(
    :: Check that the command sqlcmd.exe is on the path.
    for %%X in (sqlcmd.exe) do (SET FOUND_SQLCMD=%%~$PATH:X)
    IF not defined FOUND_SQLCMD (
        ECHO Script failed, unable to find sqlcmd.exe on the path
        ECHO Make sure sqlcmd.exe is available on the path to run this script
        ECHO Exiting the script
        exit /B 500
    )

    SET /P "DB_USERNAME=Enter the database user name:"
    SET /P "DB_PASSWORD=Enter the database user name:"

    :: Call the sqlcmd executable
    call sqlcmd.exe -S %SCRIPT_SERVER% -U %DB_USERNAME% -P %DB_PASSWORD% -i %DDL_FILE% -o %SCRIPT_RESULT_LOG%   

    ECHO(
    ECHO Call to sqlcmd.exe is complete. Please check the log file for the ddl
    ECHO(
) 

ECHO(
ECHO #########################################
ECHO # 
ECHO # Completed at %DATE% %TIME%
ECHO # 
ECHO #########################################
ECHO( 
EXIT /B 0
```

My question is, how do I break this up into subroutines such that the script will run successfully over multiple iterations? When I try to break up the section between the following:

IF [%SCRIPT_EXECUTE%]=="1" (
  GOTO MySubroutine
)

I find that the subroutine never gets called.

Similarly, I have noticed inconsistencies with variables set at the global script level that are later called in a subroutine; specifically, they are coming in as null. As you can see, I initialize all variables at the outset of the script in the hopes of not having this issue.

Your feedback is welcome and thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Try : `IF [%SCRIPT_EXECUTE%]==[1]`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. It seems my understanding of variables in windows scripts needs some work. Just reading on enabling delayed expansion, which looks to be the cause of my issue.

Comment: With a better understanding of how Windows batch files expand variable values, I decided instead to pull the stuff under IF [%SCRIPT_EXECUTE%]=="1" ( into a separate, common batch file, which then just required a call action. This was an easier way than trying to get around the hacks I have seen for getting variable values correct inside code blocks.

Comment: Also, per sachadee, I added the additional brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a better understanding of how Windows batch files expand variable values, I decided instead to pull the stuff under IF [%SCRIPT_EXECUTE%]=="1" ( into a separate, common batch file, which then just required a call action. This was an easier way than trying to get around the hacks I have seen for getting variable values correct inside code blocks. Also, per sachadee, I added the additional brackets.